# UIScrollView: disable scrolling when zooming

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, scroll, zooming

Could somebody advice how to disable scrolling when zooming in iOS4?
I have an utility which work on iOS3 and I disabled the scrolling during zoom by overriding `setTransform` method in content view, for example:

```
- (void)setTransform:(CGAffineTransform)newValue;
{ 
 [(UIScrollView*)self.superview setScrollEnabled:NO];
 [super setTransform:newValue];
}
```

but in iOS4 this trick doesn't work.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not think you can unless the content size is less than the scroll view’s frame for the duration of the zoom and any transforming that takes place. (i.e. a zoom operation makes the content area larger, once the content area is greater than the frame the scroll view scrolls. Therefore the content area must always be smaller than the frame.)

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use some of the UIScrollViewDelegate methods like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view //available starting with iOS 3.2
{
     [scrollView setScrollEnabled:FALSE];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale
{
     if(scale == 1) 
        [scrollView setScrollEnabled:TRUE];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried George's method as it seemed it would work but had no luck. Checked docs and it says "When scrolling is disabled, the scroll view does not accept touch events; it forwards them up the responder chain." so this couldn't work as we are receiving the zoom touch events. So I tried the following and it worked...

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view
{
    peggedContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
}

- (void) scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{
    scrollView.contentOffset = peggedContentOffset;
}
```

This works by grabbing the contentOffset when our zoom starts and constantly resetting it while we're zooming. I am sure a bit more fancy code could center the zoom on your zoom point whereas this just locks the top of the tableview... but it does the job.